# Is the following function a metric on $\Bbb R^2$?

Tags: metric-spaces

Is the following function a metric on $\Bbb R^2$?

> $d((x_1,x_2),(y_1,y_2))=|x_1|+|x_2|+|y_1|+|y_2|$

Now $d((x_1,x_2),(y_1,y_2))=0\iff (x_1,x_2)=(y_1,y_2)=0$

Also the other conditions are satisfied.Hence it is a metric.

But the answer is given that it is not a metric.Where am I wrong?Please help.

Comment: A [metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_(mathematics)) must satisfy $d(P,Q)=0\iff P=Q$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that, for instance, $d((1,2),(1,2))=6 \neq 0.$